# create field for load images

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a code that outputs fields for the user to fill in (code below. I have shortened it here for ease of reading.). I would like to add one more field to this form, which can upload various photos from the phone gallery (preferably with the ability to delete a photo if the user made a mistake when choosing). How can I implement this?

```
class FormForDeviceService extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _FormForDeviceService();
}

class _FormForDeviceService extends State {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
        child: Form(key: _formKey, child: Column(children: <Widget>[

          new Text('What is problem', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),),
          new TextFormField(decoration: const InputDecoration(
            hintText: 'Describe the problem',),
              
          ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: (){if(_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {_formKey.currentState?.reset();
            ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                const SnackBar(content: Text('Form completed successfully', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),),
                  backgroundColor: Colors.yellow,));
            }},
            child: const Text('Submit', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),),
            style: ButtonStyle(backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.yellow)),)
        ],)));
  }
}
```

Page at the moment
[image]

my expectations (or something similar)
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An another approach is here-
(I have made a separate widget to handle all these things and you just need to attach it in any scrollable widget)
my code is as follow:

Main Code with that custom widget:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:image_memory/image_picker_widget.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(GetMaterialApp(title: 'Flutter', home: Flutter()));
}

class Flutter extends StatefulWidget {
  const Flutter({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Flutter> createState() => _FlutterState();
}

class _FlutterState extends State<Flutter> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Flutter'),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            //This is the widget I am talking about
            ImagePickerWidget()
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And now the code for that custom widget:

```
import 'dart:typed_data';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';

class ImagePickerWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const ImagePickerWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<ImagePickerWidget> createState() => _ImagePickerWidgetState();
}

class _ImagePickerWidgetState extends State<ImagePickerWidget> {
  late List<CustomImage> images;
  late double size;
  late ImagePicker imagePicker;
  late int idGenerator;

  @override
  void initState() {
    images = [];
    size = 100;
    idGenerator = 0;
    imagePicker = ImagePicker();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              pickImage();
            },
            child: Text('Pick Image')),
        Wrap(
            children: images.map((image) {
          return Stack(children: [
            SizedBox(
                height: size,
                width: size,
                child: ClipRRect(
                    child: Image.memory(
                  image.imageData,
                  fit: BoxFit.fill,
                ))),
            Positioned(
                right: 4,
                top: 4,
                child: InkWell(
                    onTap: () {
                      //delete image
                      images.removeWhere(
                          (element) => element.imageData == image.imageData);
                      setState(() {});
                    },
                    child: Container(
                        color: Colors.white, child: Icon(Icons.clear))))
          ]);
        }).toList())
      ],
    );
  }

  Future<void> pickImage() async {
    // XFile? image = await imagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera);
    XFile? image = await imagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
    if (image != null) {
      Uint8List imageData = await image.readAsBytes();
      int id = idGenerator++;
      images.add(CustomImage(imageData: imageData, id: id));
      setState(() {});
    }
  }
}

class CustomImage {
  Uint8List imageData;
  int id;

  CustomImage({required this.imageData, required this.id});
}
```

You can customize the widget in order to use the images list of that widget or you can simply pass the callbacks for that.

Comment: Just tell me when I click on the button 'Submit' in my code. At me all form is cleared as I registered _formKey.currentState?.reset();
But the photo field remains. How can I make it clear the entire form?

Comment: Just clear the images list (images.clear()) and for that purpose you need to customize the ImagePickerWidget by adding an extra field for the Images list in the widget constructor so that you clear the list when the submit button is pressed

Comment: Could you show with a code example? I'm new and don't understand everything yet

Comment: Posted the modified code in your new question.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

we store file here your can use path(string) instead file

```
List<File> myfile = [];
```

image_picker package used here to pick image

```
  image_picker: ^0.8.4+10
```

call like this in your code

```
        Container(
            height: 200,
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(4),
            child: PickPhoto())
```

**Pick photo widget**

```
class PickPhoto extends StatefulWidget {
  const PickPhoto({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<PickPhoto> createState() => _PickPhotoState();
}

class _PickPhotoState extends State<PickPhoto> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Material(
      child: Row(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: Container(
                width: 45,
                height: 45,
                child: ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: () async {
                      var file =
                          await picker?.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);

                      setState(() {
                        myfile.add(File(file!.path));
                      });
                    },
                    child: Text("Add Photo"))),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: ListView.builder(
                // physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                itemCount: myfile.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) => Container(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(4),
                      height: 175,
                      width: 125,
                      child: Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                        children: [
                          Align(
                            alignment: Alignment.topRight,
                            child: IconButton(
                              onPressed: () {
                                setState(() {
                                  myfile.removeAt(index);
                                });
                              },
                              icon: Icon(Icons.close),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Expanded(
                            child: Container(
                              child: myfile[index] == null
                                  ? Text("")
                                  : Image.file(
                                      myfile[index],
                                      fit: BoxFit.fill,
                                    ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    )),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**SampleCode**

```
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';

ImagePicker? picker;

void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  picker = ImagePicker();
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'MySQL Test',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Column(
        children: [FormForDeviceService()],
      ),
    );
  }
}

List<File> myfile = [];
List<int> f = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
List<bool> fs = [false, false, false, true, true];

class FormForDeviceService extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _FormForDeviceService();
}

class _FormForDeviceService extends State {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
        child: Form(
            key: _formKey,
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                new Text(
                  'What is problem',
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
                ),
                new TextFormField(
                  decoration: const InputDecoration(
                    hintText: 'Describe the problem',
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                    height: 200,
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(4),
                    child: PickPhoto()),
                ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
                      _formKey.currentState?.reset();
                      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(const SnackBar(
                        content: Text(
                          'Form completed successfully',
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                        ),
                        backgroundColor: Colors.yellow,
                      ));
                    }
                  },
                  child: const Text(
                    'Submit',
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                  ),
                  style: ButtonStyle(
                      backgroundColor:
                          MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.yellow)),
                )
              ],
            )));
  }
}

class PickPhoto extends StatefulWidget {
  const PickPhoto({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<PickPhoto> createState() => _PickPhotoState();
}

class _PickPhotoState extends State<PickPhoto> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Material(
      child: Row(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: Container(
                width: 45,
                height: 45,
                child: ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: () async {
                      var file =
                          await picker?.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);

                      setState(() {
                        myfile.add(File(file!.path));
                      });
                    },
                    child: Text("Add Photo"))),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: ListView.builder(
                // physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                itemCount: myfile.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) => Container(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(4),
                      height: 175,
                      width: 125,
                      child: Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                        children: [
                          Align(
                            alignment: Alignment.topRight,
                            child: IconButton(
                              onPressed: () {
                                setState(() {
                                  myfile.removeAt(index);
                                });
                              },
                              icon: Icon(Icons.close),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Expanded(
                            child: Container(
                              child: myfile[index] == null
                                  ? Text("")
                                  : Image.file(
                                      myfile[index],
                                      fit: BoxFit.fill,
                                    ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    )),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```